# Product of two symmetric matrices: If one orthogonal matrix is known, find the other one

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Let $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a product of two symmetric matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$:

$$T = AB$$

By the Spectral Theorem, $A$ and $B$ each have an eigendecomposition $A = UD_AU^T$ and $B = VD_BV^T$, where $U,V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are orthogonal matrices and $D_A, D_B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are diagonal matrices:

$$T = UD_AU^TVD_BV^T$$

Suppose both $D_A$ and $D_B$ have at least one non-zero diagonal entry. If I know what $U$ is, is it possible to determine what $V$ is?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Why is it not possible?

Comment: Let's say $D_B$ has $m \leq n$ non-zero diagonal entries. Is it still not possible to find $m$ of the $V$ vectors which make up $T$?